# Downloaded app from Appstore hangs on first screen in ios 8.1.2?

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios8, app-store

I have uploaded app on appstore tested on for ios 7.0 and 8.0. Now I brought new iphone 6 (iOS 8.1.2) and downloaded same app from appstore. When I open it, its get hang on first screen. But when I am running same app from Xcode its working fine. Help me if anyone knows.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update Xcode to 6.1 and also use updated versions of frameworks or third party you are using.